# How can I make a dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a dropdown menu in HTML/CSS/JS and I can't find any sources that can help me. Do you have any way that an dropdown menu will work in this environment? If you have answers please post it, it'll help a lot.

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css" data-n-g="">
</head>
<html>

<body>
    <script src="js/dropdown.js"></script>
    <ul id="sellersbox">
        <li style="border-radius: 8px;border: 2px solid gray;box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);">
            <div class="objcontainer1">
                <h3 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 24px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer1title">IPhone X</h3>
                <p style="font-size: 17px;color: black;text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;display: table;background-position-y: 50%;">&starf;&starf;&starf;&starf;&star;</p>

                <a><img src="img/testimage.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;display:block; margin:0 auto;" alt="" class="objcontainer1image"></a>
                <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer1seller">Seller: <b>Sago</b></p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer1price"><b>$350.00</b></p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer1brief">This is my brief description</p>
                <a href="http://codeforum.org/"><button type="button" class="objcontainer1view" style="width: 34%; display: block; margin:0 auto;background-color: white;font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">View</button></a>
                &nbsp;
                <div class="dropdown1">
                    <button type="button" class="objcontainer1expand" style="width: 34%; display: block; margin:0 auto;background-color: white;font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">Expand</button>
                    <div class="dropdown1content">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer1test">foobar</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </li>
        <li style="border-radius: 8px;border: 2px solid gray;box-shadow: 0 12px 16px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.24),0 17px 50px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);">
            <div class="objcontainer2">
                <h3 style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 24px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer2title">2070 Super</h3>
                <p style="font-size: 17px;color: black;text-align: center;margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;display: table;background-position-y: 50%;">&starf;&starf;&starf;&star;&star;</p>

                <a><img src="img/testimage.jpg" style="width:100px;height:100px;display:block; margin:0 auto;" alt="" class="objcontainer2image"></a>
                <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 16px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer2seller">Seller: <b>FooBarGuy</b></p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer1price"><b>$525.00</b></p>
                <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer2brief">This is my brief description</p>
                <a href="http://codeforum.org/"><button type="button" class="objcontainer2view" style="width: 34%; display: block; margin:0 auto;background-color: white;font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">View</button></a>
                &nbsp;
                <div class="dropdown1">
                    <button type="button" class="objcontainer1expand" style="width: 34%; display: block; margin:0 auto;background-color: white;font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;">Expand</button>
                    <div class="dropdown1content">
                        <p style="font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;font-size: 14px;text-align: center;" class="objcontainer1test">foobar</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

From [W3 Schools Dropdown Menu tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_dropdowns.asp)

```css
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
          <a href="#">Link 1</a>
          <a href="#">Link 2</a>
          <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is stolen from w3schools.com. You could replace my classes etc. to make it much easier.

Comment: And not :hover dropdowns.

Comment: which kind of dropdown menu do you want?

Comment: [here](https://jsfiddle.net/t2uyjvhn/4/) If you would help out, can you pretty please replace my classes & etc. instead of theirs.

Comment: is it now what you want? I updated in your link

Comment: @JohnDoe You have to cite your work.  If this did come from W3, you need to state so explicitly.

Comment: @zero298, yeah I know I just felt that “stole” was a little strong. But yeah looking back, I think it’s fair to say stole, and he definitely should’ve told the source.

Comment: Thanks, guys for your comments. I am new in Stack overflow I will mention the source of my code in the future. yes, I copied from W3school and I don't know whether it is allowed or not to copy the code from other sources for helping people.